# Android: onLongClickListener while - Falls into infinite loop and hangs app

Tags: android, runnable

I am making audio player and I got all other parts working except for fast forward and rewind buttons.

I didn't know how to make it so when I hold down fast forward or rewind button - it would increment progress and when let go it would stop and start playing music from that part.

I wrote this:

```
   forwardButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            while(v.isPressed()){
            currentProgress.setProgress((currentProgress.getProgress()+1));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but when I hold down fast forward, the app falls into infinite loop basically and hangs causing android to give me option to Wait or Terminate.

I think I need to implement Runnable on it and do it via that to avoid hanging but I am not sure how to do it.

Help?

Variables:

```
forwardButton = Fast Forward button.
currentProgress = seekbar for music.
mPlayer = music player.
```

Comment: You cannot use a while() loop or similar blocking operation in a UI event.  Instead, you must convert your design to a stateful architecture, ie, setting flags or changing tracked state on each action, and then take resulting actions when your flags or state indicate that the necessary steps which should cause this have been taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do it like that. Instead, use a handler and inside the runnable include your while bucle which will be posting `setProgress()` on your main thread. Everytime you post a forward order, make a delay of X seconds, then check if button keeps clicked, if so, repost runnable.